# How can I find the residue of this function at $z=0$?

Tags: complex-numbers, laurent-series

How can I find the residue of

$$\frac{\text{sin}(\frac{1}{z})}{z^2+1}\quad ?$$

at $z=0$? In order to find this, I tried to calculate $a_{-1}$ in the Laurent series, and then arrived at $$\frac{\text{sin}(\frac{1}{z})}{z^2+1}=\frac{1}{z^2+1}\sum^{\infty}_{n=0}\frac{(-1)^n}{(2n+1)!}\cdot\left(\frac{1}{z}\right)^n,$$

but I don't know what to do next.

Comment: First, replace $\frac{1}{z^2 + 1} = \frac{1}{1 - -z^2}$ with its geometric series and call that $G$.  Since you have a product of series, you have (one term from $G$, one term from the sine series) pairs that contribute to the $1/z$ term of the product.  Can you write the sum of just those contributions?  Example pairs: $(1, \frac{-1}{3!}z^{-1})$, $(-z^2, \frac{-1}{7!} z^{-3})$, ...  (Note: you may have some difficulties summing the coefficient of that term, because $\sin(1/z)$ has an essential singularity at $z = 0$...)

Comment: can you clarify more about the product and the pairs ? @EricTowers

Comment: Your last display is "function I study ${}=G \cdot ($ series for $\sin(1/z) )$", a product of two series.  By distributivity, the result is a sum of "for each term in $G$, for each term in the sine series, the product of those two terms".  (If we are being careful, we only make this claim for any choices of partial sums of the two series then take usual limits and show convergence.)  So, for each choice of term in the sine series there is at most one term in $G$ that results in a contribution to $z^{-1}$.  Find those pairs and sum them.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As you been told in the comments, you need series (Taylor's or Laurent's) around $\;z=0\;$ , and for this you need only a tiny circle around this point:

$$\frac{\sin\frac1z}{1+z^2}=\frac1{1+z^2}\cdot\sin\frac1z=\left(1-z^2+z^4-z^6+\ldots\right)\left(\frac1z-\frac1{3!z^3}+\frac1{5!z^5}-\ldots\right)\;(*)$$

The first series converges (absolutely and uniformly) for $\;|z^2|<1\iff |z|<1\;$, and the second one for any $\;|z|>0\;$, and we want the coefficient of $\;z^{-1}=\frac1z\;$ in the product series, so we multiply:

$$(*)=\ldots+\left(1\cdot\frac1z-\frac{z^2}{3!z^3}+\frac{z^4}{5!z^5}-\ldots+\right)+\ldots=\ldots+\left(1-\frac1{3!}+\frac1{5!}-\ldots\right)\frac1z+\ldots$$

and there you have your coefficient $\;c_{-1}\;$ ... Recognize now that alternating series and solve.